# While angular upgrade 12 to 13 getting issue

Tags: angular, angular12, angular13

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'styles' of undefined;

For this above issue, suggested to add  ng update ngx-build-plus@13 --force from internet, so I have add that again getting different issue "Package 'ngx-build-plus' is not a dependency".

If anybody face this issue let me know how to rectify.

Welcome you suggestions

Comment: What's the question here? And how are we even supposed to help you out with the information you wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure why these are the suggestions you got.
try to point angular to the right styles file in the angualr.json -> build section.
sounds like an import issue to me.
also verify you have upgraded angular material as well. (if you're using it)

anyway, any other information could assist us to help you.